# Spring cloud gateway Path Route Predicate match failed

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

In following spring cloud gateway config, i am tring to match path ends with `/favicon.ico`, but it can not match path: `/gitBooks/100/abc/favicon.ico`

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: favicon
          uri: forward:///favicon.ico
          predicates:
            - Path=**/favicon.ico
```

the spring cloud gateway print following log:

```
2020-02-04 22:57:35.703 TRACE 28356 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.c.g.h.p.RoutePredicateFactory        : Pattern "[**/favicon.ico]" does not match against value "/gitBooks/100/abc/favicon.ico"
2020-02-04 22:57:35.703 TRACE 28356 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : No RouteDefinition found for [Exchange: GET http://localhost:8080/gitBooks/100/abc/favicon.ico]
```

I don't understand, and am wondering how to write the path predicator to match path endswith `favicon.ico`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the PathMatcher does not work, at last I wrote a customized Predicate:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: favicon
          uri: forward:///favicon.ico
          predicates:
            - Favicon=
```

```java
@Component
public class FaviconRoutePredicateFactory extends AbstractRoutePredicateFactory<FaviconRoutePredicateFactory.Config> {
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(FaviconRoutePredicateFactory.class);


    public FaviconRoutePredicateFactory() {
        super(Config.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate<ServerWebExchange> apply(Config config) {
        return exchange -> {
            String path = exchange.getRequest().getURI().getRawPath();
            return !path.equals("/favicon.ico") && path.endsWith("favicon.ico");
        };
    }

    public static class Config {
    }
}
```